# How to "restart" application ios

Tags: ios, xcode, viewcontroller

So I have an app where a user goes through 3 view controllers and then submits a picture to Facebook.  After they submit it to Facebook, I want them to be able to choose to restart the process over again, as if they had re-launched the app.

How could I do this?

thanks

Comment: `-popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` ?

Comment: [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];    
?

It isn't a navigation controller though...Its just a viewcontroller

Comment: how are you navigating to these other views?

Comment: FacebookUpload *newView = [[FacebookUpload alloc]initWithNibName:@"FacebookUpload" bundle:nil];
    newView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:newView animated:YES];


Just loading the view controllers? I want the app to restart and clear all data basically

Comment: dismiss the modal view controller then.

Comment: That goes back to the second view though.  

Right now I have: VC1>VC2>VC3 and I want to go from VC3>VC1 somehow?

Comment: How in the heck did you present three modal view controllers?

Comment: You start on the first screen, do some stuff, click a button and it loads the second screen.  You do some stuff on the second screen, click a button and it loads the third screen.  You do some stuff on the third screen and I want to be able to click a button to return back to the first screen

Comment: From what I understand, you pushed from 1 to 2, then presented a modal view from 2-3.  Dismiss the modal view (3-2), then popToRootViewControllerAnimated: to undo the push (2-1), *et viola!*

Comment: I think 1-2 and 2-3 were both modal.  I wanted transitions when I changed view controllers, thats why I used them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, because you haven't been clear about your navigation patterns, I'll show the two kinds of transitions and their opposites:

**Push-Pop**: Is created by pushing a new UIViewController onto the navigation stack using

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:exampleController animated:YES];
```

It is counteracted by

```
[self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

**Modal View**: Is created by presenting a new UIViewController over the current one.

```
[self presentModalViewController:exampleController animated:YES];
```

It is not on the navigation stack, so the possibility of presenting another modal view within the first modal view is not available.  It is counteracted by calling

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

from within the modal view itself.

Comment: Thank you! I just ended up reloading the original view, but these are good to have.  thanks